# Is there any way to disable the Home button on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications

My professor asked me to help him out to find some information about the iPad.

We are going to buy like 10 iPads to give it out to our senior of the school board and we want only the PDF file that we are going to sync it to be appear on the screen.

I know this is almost impossible without jailbreak, but the iPad wouldn't be able to jailbreak and the people who going to get the iPad they don't really know how to use them, and if they sometime press on the home button they will mess it up and don't know how to get back to the screen that have PDF file.

So I heard of Kiosk Pro but really I don't know how it works and I don't know if they will spend that much of money to buy the license again to this task.

So I want to know some information from you guys if there is any demo app like what Apple does put the iPad 1 beside each of the products to show the specification of the product and have the case cover the home button so no one can go back to home screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 6 now has a software feature to block variable parts of the screen and hardware buttons. The feature is called "Guided Access". A PIN is needed to unlock the device afterwards.

[How to use Guided Access](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2012/09/new-feature-in-ios-6-how-to-use-guided-access)

Answer (score 2):

Not easily via software. There is a cottage industry of caps to place over the home button to make it hard or impossible for toddlers to press that button.

The [bubcap](http://papercliprobot.com/) is one such product but in your case, it might not help if the users are determined to press the button.

The simplest solution may be to buy an iPad case that covers the Home button, or modify an existing case that doesn't (e.g. glue a cover over the button hole).

Answer (score 0):

The [OtterBox Defender](http://www.otterbox.com/defender-series-cases) case would be my choice to really lock down the home button. You can modify the rubber button so it's not possible to press or insert a strong material if the unmodified case isn't enough to deter casual button presses.

It's not as good as the custom software for digital signage that Apple rolls in their retail stores (with demo mode, limited access, etc...) but might work if you want something more secure than a deterrent product like [bubcap](http://papercliprobot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said, using Guided Access which is included in iOS 6,7,8,9 and 10 would be a cheaper, more reliable option than the two hardware button protectors.

You can simply go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access, then turn it on. You will then have to set a passcode that the students won't know by tapping Passcode settings > Set Guided Access Passcode.

Now go into the app you wish to keep the students in, and triple click the home button. It may come up with a box saying Accessibility Shortcuts. If so, just click Guided Access and you can continue. It will say Guided Access Started. You must now triple click the home button once more, and tap Guided Access again if applicable. Enter the passcode you set before and enable touch if it is not already enabled, then under Hardware Buttons hit Options.

If you don't want them turning the device off, turn off Sleep/Wake Button. Now hit resume, and you will not be able to close the app until someone who knows the passcode triple clicks the home button, enters the passcode, then hits end.